# create procedure for correct DB data from xlsx (cursors?)

Tags: mysql, sql

As title, I was wondering if is possible to create a MySQL procedure that change some existing data by checking an xlsx file.
For example, I have a DB with thousands records, and several columns, but few columns only in certain cases contains wrong data.
I have an excel correction table like this.

| old column 1 | old column 2 | new column 1 | new column 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9f9rgg | hf4f | Smith | 27 |
| gfhgfg | bv3u | Johnson | 22 |
| fghgfh | sduf | Williams | 35 |
| 4355gt | xndo | Brown | 34 |
| g74f66 | fd37 | Jones | 23 |
| 8rhg9e | cvxn | Garcia | 30 |

I'd like to make a query, maybe a procedure is better, that check for old values replacing them with new values, basing on this table.
After some searches I read about those "Cursors" I think it could works but I miss something.
Am I going in the right way?
PS: In the preview I see the table correctly, I don't understand why isn't correctly showed after post creation.
By the way here is the table in HTML format so you can run it and see what do I mean.

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; height: 126px;" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 18px;">
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">old column 1</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">old column 2</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">new column 1</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">new column 2</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 18px;">
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">d8ag8gsd</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">fff3f3</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">Smith</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">27</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 18px;">
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">54t54t</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">reeee</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">Johnson</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">22</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 18px;">
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">t54t5t</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">tetght</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">Williams</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">35</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 18px;">
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">t545t5t</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">thtrgc</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">Brown</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">34</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 18px;">
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">jkhgfy</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">5654gt</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">Jones</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">23</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 18px;">
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">65y6th</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">5jju7s</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">Garcia</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">30</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I think you will have to write a program to read excel and update db

Comment: @RiggsFolly Hm, do you think it's not possible to make this using procedures and cursors? I remember years ago I seen a video of a dude making it using Heidi SQL.